# How to sort an associative array alphabetically in php?

Tags: php, sql, sorting, associative-array, alphabetical

I am getting my array values from database. and it is just names of users.
Iam printing them as it as they are retrieved , I want to print them Alphabetical order of their names (Ascending Order). How can I do this ?

```
foreach($common_follows as $row) // $common_follows contains the IDs of users
            {

        $names=$obj2->get_user_name($row); //this function gets the name from user ID

                    while   ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($names)) // For getting the name of the person being followed
                    {
                sort($rows['name']); //Not seems to sort
                        echo '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$rows['user_id'].'/picture?type=normal" width="65" height="20" id="fbthumb">';
                        echo $rows['name']."<br>";
                      $count_common++;
                    }
            }
```

That sort function does not seem to work , since at each loop iteration a single name is returned .

Comment: Why not do the ordering in the SQL query?

Comment: I am retrieving each name from its user_id. Sorting bu userid does not sort them alphabetically. How can I use that sort function ?

Comment: What's behind the foreach()?

Comment: it is the code that retrieves all user IDs from database and saves them to `$common_follows` array.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a PHP array by key using `ksort`. if you want to sort by value, use `asort`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to move the sorting to your MySQL you could do it like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
ORDER BY name ASC
```

This is only an example you'll need to match your table/column names.

With your example code you could make `$common_follows` into a comma separated string i.e. `1,2,3...` and pass that into the query rather than looping and making multiple MySQL queries. This would look like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE id IN (1,2,3) // <-- comma separated string
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

 $fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
  sort($fruits);
 foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

  ?>
```